# I am trying to import the CSS file into the base html template file but it is not applying the style. I am trying to define it externally

Tags: html, css, web-development-server

The style in css is not being imported.

Here is my  tag of base HTML file (base.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homeDesign.css"/>
    <title> {% block title %}Base{% endblock %} </title>
</head>
```

Here is my CSS file ("homeDesign.css"):

```
@charset "UTF-8";

.note-card {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  }

  .container,body {
    background-color: #95a1b0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  .sub-container {
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 10px;
    justify: space-around;
  }
```

Homepage html where the css is supposed to be applied (home.html):

```
<h1 style="color: #1b0e02;">Notes</h1>
  <div class="sub-container">
  {% for note in user.notes %}
    <div class="note-card"> 
      <button type="button" class="close" on-click="deleteNote({{ note.id }})">&times;</button>
     </br>
      {{ note.text }} 
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

**When I try to apply the style inline inside the head tag using , it works. But I want to define it externally.

Here is the screenshot of folder heirarchy for your reference:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ3rx.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the index.js is rendering the html file, and it is not in the same directory as the css file. I would try providing the absolute path to the CSS instead of the relative path to see if that works.
for example, try this instead,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/homeDesign.css">
```

Comment: Tried the above path. Still not working :/